# btrfs subvolumes not auto mounted after set-default

Tags: linux, btrfs

I'm using [btrfs-sxbackup](https://github.com/masc3d/btrfs-sxbackup) to create local snapshots. It creates a technical subvolume in `/.sxbackup` and creates readonly snapshots in its subfolder. All subvolumes are automatically mounted when OS boots, nothing needed to be specified in fstab.

This one time I tried to restore a snapshot:

```
btrfs subvol snapshot /.sxbackup/sx-20190308-070926-utc /.before-5.0
btrfs subvol set-default /.before-5.0
```

Upon reboot the technical subvolume `/.sxbackup/` is not mounted. Now every time I have to mount it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On BTRFS, subvolumes form the "snapshot barrier." Meaning, when you snapshot a subvolume which contains subvolumes, the nested subvolumes are not included in the snapshot.

> But care must be taken when snapshots should be made (**nested
>   subvolumes are not part of a snapshot**, and as of now, there are no
>   recursive snapshots)... - source https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/SysadminGuide#Nested

If you check your snapshots in `/.sxbackup` you'll find that none of them contain the `.sxbackup` subvolume.

To make the snapshots available in a consistent fashion, consider adding a read-only mount-point of the `.sxbackup` subvolume to some other place on the filesystem. For example:

**/etc/fstab**

```
/dev/sd* /mnt/snapshots btrfs ro,subvol=/.sxbackup 0 0
```

The above example mounts the `.sxbackup` subvolume at `/mnt/snapshots` regardless of which subvolume is the default.

Comment: I'm starting to think that installing OS to the top-level subvolume was a bad idea

Comment: Yeah... a flat layout provides more flexibility.